# Local Turnkey Protoryper & ServerSide jobs

Tags: mdriven

I use Local Turnkey Protoryper and my model has viewmodels with ServerSide jobs. Is there any possibility to run that jobs without having MDriven server installed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - Currently the serverside jobs need the MDrivenServer. 
You can simulate with the ocl debugger by doing the same thing as the the job was supposed to do.

Comment: This answer is old - MDriven now implements communication with webapi for the normal client server operations